# Multiple items same line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am having a small issue with some html code. I am trying to create a sample document for sparkle release notes, so I created some highlighted boxes containing either "fixed","added" or "improved", and then on the right should go the release notes. What instead happens is that the 'something' word gets pushed onto a new line like a new item but without the dot at the beginning. Is there a way to push it up on the same line as the box??

This is what I have so far:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<title>Release Notes</title>

<body>
    <ul>
    <li><span class='fixed-square'>Fixed</span>Something</li>
    <li><span class='added-square'>Added</span></li>
    <li><span class='improved-square' >Improved</span></li>
</ul>   
</body>
```

style.css

```
.fixed-square {
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.added-square {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.improved-square {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}


body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Thank you very much to all of you, for the quick answer. To recap I went from this:

```
.improved-square {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to this:

```
.improved-square {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;  <----------
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change display: block on display: inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1):

Swap out the `display:block` for `display:inline-block`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Cd9vK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixed-square {
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: white;
    display: block; // this is actually sending something in second line try adding display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9vK/4/)

You have to add in css like

```
   ul li
   {
     display:inline;
     float : left;
     margin :5px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use  inline-block
[spam link removed]

Comment: Can you provide more information?  This answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: The link did not answer the question at all, it was just spam. And without it (I removed it), the answer has so little content that it should be a comment instead.